# assign function type to an object's method

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

What is the syntax to assign `MyFn` type to the `sayHello` function and STILL keep them separated?

```
type MyFn = string => string;

const obj = {
  sayHello: name => `Hello ${ name }`
};
```

I can do this:

```
const nonMethod: MyFn = name => `Hello ${ name }`;
```

But I cannot find a way to type the object's method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way, but it's a bit ugly:

```
type MyFn = string => string;

const obj = {
  sayHello: ((name => `Hello ${ name }`): MyFn)
};
```

Most of the time, I either give a type and then add to an object, or I specify the type of the object `{sayHello: MyFn}`.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't look as ugly as I was expecting it but yeah defining a separate object type and using that works too.