# Applying a function type to an object's arrow function member in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

Given the following object:

```
const parameters = {
  someNumberMember: 1 as number,
  someArrowFunctionMember: () => { return true; }
}
```

Is there a way to directly assign a type definition to `someArrowFunctionMember`? I mean a "complete" type definition of the function, not defining the parameter and return types. So something like this:

```
...
  someArrowFunctionMember: () => { return true; } as DesiredType,
...                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't work
```

Context: I know there's 2 better ways to do this.

1. Assign a type to `parameters` that defines `someArrowFunctionMember`'s type like this:

```
type ParametersType = {
  someNumberMember: number;
  someArrowFunctionMember: () => boolean;
}

const parameters: ParametersType = {
  someNumberMember: 1 as number,
  someArrowFunctionMember: () => { return true },
}
```

2. Extract the arrow function into a variable like this:

```
const handler: () => boolean = () => { return true };

const parameters = {
  someNumberMember: 1 as number,
  someArrowFunctionMember: handler,
}
```

I'm just curious if there is a syntax that allows me to do this directly.

I tried using the `as` keyword because it works when using a classic function:

```
const parameters = {
  someNumberMember: 1 as number,
  someArrowFunctionMember: function() {return true;} as () => boolean,
}                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ works like a charm
```

I also tried using type casting with the pointy brackets because it also works on classic functions:

```
const parameters = {
  someNumberMember: <number> 1,
  someArrowFunctionMember: <Function> function() {return true;},
}
```

Note: This initially didn't work until I realized the problem wasn't Typescript itself but rather using TS in conjunction with JSX, which makes sense. After disabling `jsx` in `tsconfig`, it works (at least in TS playground).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946766) but it doesn't seem to work anymore or there's something in my `tsconfig` preventing it from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried placing the whole function within brackets:

```
...
  someArrowFunctionMember: (() => { return true; }) as DesiredType,
...
```

**Note:**

Typescript will infer the type implicitly so usually you dot need a cast.

Comment: That... works. I was so sure that I tried this variant, but I guess I didn't. Sometimes TS syntax is a bit... frustrating :D. Thanks for your help!

To your note: Yes, usually that would work. However, when I have a single function argument that I immediately destructure, Typescript asks me to type the parameters.

`someFunction: ({first, second}) => { return true; }` without type casting results in: `TS7031: Binding element 'first' implicitly has an 'any' type.`